# What are the other factors of x if we know 2, 4, and 9 are factors.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, prime-factorization

The factors of x include 2, 4, 9. Which of the following are also factors of x?

{1, 3, 5, 6, 8, 10, 12, 18, 24, 36}

Apparently the correct answer is {1, 3, 6, 12, 18, and 36} but I have trouble seeing how 36 is a factor and 24 is not. Whats the best method for finding which numbers in the set are factors.

Also since 2 is already a factor of 4 does the extra 2 they provide count as a distinct factor of x or could in be included in the 4? As in, if they said the factors were 4 and 9 would that be a different problem?

Comment: What if $x$ itself is $36$? Then $24$ is not a factor. The largest power of $2$ that we know divides $x$ is $4=2^2$. To answer your final question, the fact that $4$ is a factor **guarantees** that $2$ is also a factor.

Comment: *The factors include $2,4,9$* does not mean that all primes $2,2,2,3,3$ really appear. This might also be a language issue. It is easy to confuse with "*The factors of $x$ must contain a $2$ and another $4$, and a factor $9$*.

Comment: @DietrichBurde, each of $2$, $4$ and $9$ is a factor of $36$. That’s essentially the point of the question. That’s why they included $24$ as a choice—to give one the experience of considering it and rejecting it.

Comment: @PaulTanenbaum 36 could be x but it could just as well be 72 no? They didn't say 2, 4, and 9 are the only factors here.

Comment: @DietrichBurde, the information specified in the problem can be equivalently stated as “Among the divisors of $x$ are all integers of the form $2^n3^m$, for $0\leq n\leq 2$ and $0\leq m \leq 2$.”

Comment: Yes, it could be $72\times 5=360$ too. But we don’t **know** that $24$ is a factor of $x$ because from what we are given!, $x$ **could** be $36$.

Comment: @PaulTanenbaum so to solve this question do we assume x is the lowest possible combination of the given factors and see how else to combine those factors into new factors? so 36 has prime factors 2, 2, 3, 3 and we can't build 24 from those?

Comment: Hint:  What is the literal meaning of Least Common Multiple?  Could that definition have any application to what you are trying to do.  (Spoiler:  If 2,4,9 are factors then $x$ is a multiple of $2,4,9$ and is therefore a multiple of the least common multiple of $2,4,9$. And therefore every factor of the least common multiple of $2,4,9$ must be a factor.  That we know for sure.  Is there anything else we know for sure?  [Spoiler to a spoiler: No, there isn't.])

Comment: "but it could just as well be 72 no? They didn't say 2, 4, and 9 are the only factors here."  The didn't say $7$ or $13$ or $57938754893758943798$ weren't factors either.  They all *could* be factors.  The question is what *MUST* be a factor given what we know.  We are not *assuming* $x$ is the lowest combination, but we don't know anything to assume it is not.

Comment: If they said the factors were $4$ and $9$ then you would know that $2$ is a factor. So then the factors would include $2$, $4$, and $9$. What you're expected to learn here is to recognize that sometimes inserting a number in the list of given factors doesn't change the problem at all.

Answer (score 0):

If $4$ is a factor of $x$, then by extension $2$ is a factor because $4=2^2$. Every number has $1$ as a factor as well, so we can **guarantee** that the factors of $x$ include $1$, $2^2$, and $3^2$.

If the product of all of these is a factor of $x$, then we can say that the product of any subset will also be a factor of $x$.

This means that we can say that the other factors of $x$ include
$2^2\cdot3^2$,
$2^2\cdot3$,
$2\cdot3^2$,
and $2\cdot3$.

Comment: No. The problem statement says that the factors **include** $2$, $4$, and $9$, not that all other integers are excluded as factors.

Comment: "we can say that the product of any subset will also be a factor of x" can you explain more how we know this is true? what law of mathematics allows us to search for factors by using a subset and not all the factors we have. For example if you can use 2^1 and 3^1 to say 6 is a factor why can I not also say 2^3 is a factor?

Comment: That $2$ is a factor means there exists an $n$ such that $x=2n$. Likewise, that $3$ is a factor means that $x=3m$ for some $m$. Note that because $x$ is even, so is $3m$, and since $3$ *isn’t* even, that means that $m$ *is*. So $m=2k$ for some $k$. But then $x=3\cdot 2k$, which is to say, $x=6k$. And this works because $2$ and $3$ are relatively prime.

Comment: You cannot infer from the problem statement that $2^3=8$ is a factor of $x$. Again, consider the example fact that $x$ might be $36$. The reason it might is that $36$ conforms to the description in the problem statement—having $2$, $4$, and $9$ as factors—and illustrates that the problem statement does not imply that $x$ is divisible by $8$.

Comment: @PaulTanenbaum You're right, my apologies for the bad phrasing. Fixed

Comment: Your final sentence still describes 36, 12, 18, and 6 as “**the** other factors of $x$.”